# How to create a symbolic link in the www directory?

Tags: php, windows, apache, wamp, wampserver

I'm not even sure this is the right way to do this, but I am looking for some advice. I am developing on a Mac, but using VMWare to run this project in Windows.

I am using WAMPserver 2.2A. My directories look like this:

```
C:\Users\John Doe\Development\project-web\
C:\wamp\www\
```

What I would like, is to develop my project in project-web, but have a symlink in www so I can run it in the browser with apache. This is what I tried:

```
mklink project "C:\Users\John Doe\Development\project-web\"
```

I ran into some permissions errors when trying to approach it this way. I feel like this would be better than storing the project in \www\ but I might be wrong.

Any advice would be great!

Comment: Apache generally doesn't follow symlinks by default, as they can be trivially used to break out of the document root. I'd suggest looking into using an Apache `Alias` instead to create a virtual Apache folder that maps to your development directory.

Comment: After reading that, I read about creating an Alias, and viola - it worked! Would you mind adding your comment as an answer so I can accept it?'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache generally doesn't follow symlinks by default, as they can be trivially used to break out of the document root. I'd suggest looking into using an Apache [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) instead to create a virtual Apache folder that maps to your development directory