# "repository already exists" -- error when multiple github repository directories have same name

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I use wampserver on my dev machine and I have my directories like this:

```
C:\wamp\www\website_1\www
C:\wamp\www\website_2\www
```

The reason I have it like that is so that I can have files and folders in the `website_x` directory that are above the `www` directory, where the `www` directory is the same as the `www` directory on my live server.

The problem is that I am trying to add a second repository to github and it doesn't like my folder structure. Github has me specify a folder location and a repository name. Aggravatingly, github appends the repository name onto the folder location, so if I choose:

```
C:\wamp\www\website_2\www
```

As the folder location in github, and the repository name as "myrepository", then it changes the folder location to:

```
C:\wamp\www\website_2\www\myrepository
```

Which is obviously totally wrong.

The only way to get it to work with my folder structure is to choose this as the folder:

```
C:\wamp\www\website_2\
```

And then name the repository "www," which results in the path being:

```
C:\wamp\www\website_2\www\
```

This worked fine for one repository, but since two repositories can't have the same name, I'm at an impasse.

I don't understand why github appends the name of the repository onto the file path. This seems really unintuitive, useless, and creates problems like in my case.

How can I get this working without changing the directory structure that I currently use, which is logical and works really well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

- clone the two repos anywhere else on your hardrive (`C:\GitHub\Repo1a` and `C:\GitHub\Repo2`)
- [make symlink (`MKLINK`)](http://www.windows7home.net/how-to-create-symbolic-link-in-windows-7/) between:

  - `C:\wamp\www\website_1\www` and `C:\GitHub\Repo1a`
  - `C:\wamp\www\website_2\www` and `C:\GitHub\Repo1b`

That, or look into [Alias and not VirtualHost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8539066/6309).